# LINQ-To-XML Query on Mulitple Identical Elements

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I am fairly new to LINQ and XML and am trying to work with an existing large 500k line XML file which has the same structure as the XML below.  I have figured out how to test for multiple null XElements but am totally stuck on how to search for multiple Identical XElements.

How do I get LINQ to return just contacts that work for google?

Thank you all in advanced.

```
void Main()
{
XDocument AddressBook = CreateAddressBookXML();

var query =
        from contact in AddressBook.Descendants("Contact")
        let companyelement = contact.Element("Company") 
        where companyelement != null
        let companyname    = companyelement.Descendants("CompanyName")
        where companyname != null && companyname == "Google"
        select contact;


Console.Write(query);

}


public XDocument CreateAddressBookXML() {
    XDocument result =
      new XDocument(
        new XComment("My phone book"),
        new XElement("phoneBook",
          new XComment("My friends"),
          new XElement("Contact",
            new XAttribute("name", "Ralph"),
            new XElement("homephone", "555-234-4567"),
            new XElement("cellphone", "555-345-75656"),
            new XElement("Company",
                new XElement("CompanyName","Ralphs Web Design"),
                new XElement("CompanyName","Google")
            )
        ),
          new XElement("Contact",
            new XAttribute("name", "Dave"),
            new XElement("homephone", "555-756-9454"),
            new XElement("cellphone", "555-762-1546"),
            new XElement("Company",
                new XElement("CompanyName","Google")
            )
        ),
          new XComment("My family"),
          new XElement("Contact",
            new XAttribute("name", "Julia"),
            new XElement("homephone", "555-578-1053"),
            new XElement("cellphone", "")
        ),
          new XComment("My team"),
          new XElement("Contact",
            new XAttribute("name", "Robert"),
            new XElement("homephone", "555-565-1653"),
            new XElement("cellphone", "555-456-2567"),
            new XElement("Company",
                new XElement("CompanyName","Yahoo")
                )
        )
    )
  );

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var query = from contacts in CreateAddressBookXML().Root.Descendants("Contact")
            where contacts.Element("Company") != null &&
                  contacts.Element("Company").Elements("CompanyName").
            FirstOrDefault(c => c.Value == "Google") != null
            select contacts;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but your solution only returns 1 contact.  There are two contacts with Google as the company.

Answer (score 0):

I generally prefer to mix in a bit of XPath to write these queries, it's far more compact than the LINQ equivalent.

```
var query =
    from contact in doc.XPathSelectElements("/phoneBook/Contact")
    where contact.XPathSelectElements("Company/CompanyName[.='Google']").Any()
    select contact;
```

Otherwise, using LINQ:

```
var query =
    from contact in doc.Elements("phoneBook").Elements("Contact")
    where contact.Elements("Company").Elements("CompanyName")
        .Any(c => (string)c == "Google")
    select contact;
```